VBA. Nesting if elseif within Select Case procedure
I have the following function written within VBA module as a test case. At this moment the function includes only one "Case" because I want to test it and if successful to fill with more "Case"s:
Function Insurn(indicator as String, value as Double)
    Select Case indicator
        Case string_indicator1
            If value >= 11 And value <= 99 Then
                asset_val = 5
            ElseIf value >= 6 And value <= 10 Or value >= 100 Then
                asset_val = 4
            ElseIf value >= 0 And value <= 5 Then
                asset_val = 3
            ElseIf value >= -5 And value < 0 Then
                asset_val = 2
            ElseIf value >= -14 And value < -5 Then
                asset_val = 1
            ElseIf value >= -24 And value < -14 Then
                asset_val = 0
            Else val < -24 Then
            End If
    End Select
End Function

I apply this function inputting the following data Insurn("string_indicator1", 12) and it returns 0 value. However, I expect the function to return 5.
And much more, no matter what number is assigned to the value parameter the function invariably returns 0 value.
Please help clear out how to make this function work properly.

Else val < -24 Then is not valid VBA. string_indicator1 is not the same as "string_indicator1". Put Option Explicit on top.

I think first you need to understand how UDF (User Defined Functions) work. When you create an UDF, you must assign a value to be returned by the UDF.
Something like this:
Function MYSUM(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
result = a + b
End Function

This will return zero always because I've not assigned any value to be returned. Now check this:
Function MYSUM(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
result = a + b

MYSUM = result
End Function

This will work as expected. second thing is comparing direct strings/numbers or variables. You got this line:
Case string_indicator1

Here string_indicator1 is being called as a variable, not as a direct string, and the variable is empty so actually your code is checking vs an empty variable.
So if you call your function like Insurn("string_indicator1", 12) probably you want your code something like this:
Function Insurn(indicator As String, value As Double)
'always declare your variables
Dim asset_val As Integer 'or whatever tipe you need

Select Case indicator
    Case "string_indicator1"
        If value >= 11 And value <= 99 Then
            asset_val = 5
        ElseIf value >= 6 And value <= 10 Or value >= 100 Then
            asset_val = 4
        ElseIf value >= 0 And value <= 5 Then
            asset_val = 3
        ElseIf value >= -5 And value < 0 Then
            asset_val = 2
        ElseIf value >= -14 And value < -5 Then
            asset_val = 1
        ElseIf value >= -24 And value < -14 Then
            asset_val = 0
End Select

'assign result to function!

Insurn = asset_val

End Function

Notice the modification on Case and finnaly how the code assigns the output to be returned.
Hope this can help you out

You are passing the string "string_indicator1" as argument to the function parameter indicator (so indicator = "string_indicator1")
In your case-statement, you are checking if indicator is string_indicator1, but that is not a string, but a variable. That variable is probably not defined and therefore contains the empty string. As this is not equal to the value in indicator, your whole If-ElseIf... construct is never executed. The function value is never calculated and the function will always return 0 (that's the default value in VBA).
You simply need to change the case-statement to
Case "string_indicator1"

And you should do 2 things:
Always use Option Explicit at the top of your code (in the VBA editor, use Tools->Options and on the "Editor"-Tab, check "Require Variable Declaration".
Learn to use the VBA debugger, check your code by stepping thru all statements, that helps to understand how your code works and why it fails. I recommend enter link description here, but there are millions of other tutorials.

In addition to the previous answers it will be more readable to reuse Select Case instead of repeating If - Then - ElseIf:
Select Case Value
    Case 11 To 99:           asset_val = 5
    Case 6 To 10, Is > 100:  asset_val = 4
    Case 0 To 5:             asset_val = 3
    Case -5 To 0:            asset_val = 2   ' -5 To -1
    Case -14 To -5:          asset_val = 1   ' -14 To -6
    Case -24 To -14:         asset_val = 0   ' -24 To -15
End Select

if the variable Value is of integral type, it is more clear to use the ranges provided in the comments.

Nesting Conditions (UDF)


Function Insurn(Indicator As String, Value As Double) As Variant
    
    Dim AssetValue As Variant
    
    Select Case LCase(Indicator)
        Case LCase("string_indicator1")
            If Value >= 11 And Value < 100 Then
                AssetValue = 5
            Else
                Select Case Value
                    Case Is >= 6: AssetValue = 4
                    Case Is >= 0: AssetValue = 3
                    Case Is >= -5: AssetValue = 2
                    Case Is >= -14: AssetValue = 1
                    Case Is >= -24: AssetValue = 0
                    Case Else: AssetValue = CVErr(xlErrNum) ' "Value Too Low"
                End Select
            End If
        ' add more cases:
        'Case LCase("")
        'Case LCase("")
        
        Case Else: AssetValue = CVErr(xlErrNA) ' "Indicator Not Available"
    End Select
  
    Insurn = AssetValue

End Function

